Can I mint more tokens to get money out of my meme coin?
I launched a meme coin today, I burned entire LP & I also sold all my tokens from my dev wallet. This meme coin did not go well & is already dead, But their is still money inside and it is entirely my money. I noticed the mint authority is still enabled. So is there any way I can get my money out?

If you have retained minting authority and if there are still funds available in the contract, technically you have ability to mint more token.

I do have the mint authority, and there's still funds available in the contract,
but I cant figure out how to mint more tokens.

You may follow this in this case https://chainstack.com/how-to-mint-solana-spl-tokens/amp/

It looks like someone answered your question already, but can you provide some insight on what caused your meme coin to fail? Did some bot snipe the supply and dump on you? I have concerns that validators have an unfair advantage in the Solana ecosystem and actively abusing their advantage.
